How to switch between themes in Ant Design Angular?
I have theme.less file with commented @import code lines of dark and light themes. Both themes are applying fine individually by uncommenting relevant @import code line. I want to use a button action to switch between these themes. I couldn't find a way to do this. I'll attach theme.less file bellow.
//default theme
//@import "../node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.css";

//dark theme
@import "../node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.dark.css";

I tried with wrap those @imports in css classed and toggle them with a button action. It didn't work. I'll attach the code bellow.
//default theme
//@import "../node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.css";

//dark theme
//@import "../node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.dark.css";


.default-theme {
  @import "../node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.css";
}

.dark-theme {
  @import "../node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.dark.css";
}


You can check out their docs and this GitHub repo which is pulled from the docs: https://ng.ant.design/docs/customize-theme/en and https://github.com/yangjunhan/nz-themes/tree/master

@KibéM.C thanks a lot. I didn't check the theme customization section earlier. I directly checked the dynamic theme section. I accidentally missed the relevant doc section :D.
